# Why my focus is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have data.json file is being loaded after I focus but after I focus then my datepicker is not showing  why I didn't understand. but if I focus second time I can see.. where is my mistake ?

```js
function flattenFieldsArray(arr) {
      return arr.map(function(item) {
        return item.field
      })
    }
    $(function() {
     var focused = false;
       $(document.body).one("focus", '#checkin,#checkout', function() {
          if (!focused) {
            
      
             $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
      

        // use ajax data mapped to same structure as original variables
        var firstDate = flattenFieldsArray(data.firstDate);
        var lastDate = flattenFieldsArray(data.lastDate);
        var availabledays = flattenFieldsArray(data.availabledays);
        var booked = flattenFieldsArray(data.booked);;
        var ssdays = [];

        // nothing was changed below

        var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
          from = $("#checkin").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            firstDay: 1,
            minDate: new Date(firstDate),
            maxDate: new Date(lastDate),
            onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
              var yenitarih = new Date();

              var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
              date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))

              $("#checkout").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
            },

            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
              var y = date.getFullYear().toString(); // get full year
              var m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // get month.
              var d = date.getDate().toString(); // get Day
              if (m.length == 1) {
                m = '0' + m;
              } // append zero(0) if single digit
              if (d.length == 1) {
                d = '0' + d;
              } // append zero(0) if single digit
              var currDate = y + '-' + m + '-' + d;
              if (jQuery.inArray(currDate, availabledays) >= 0) {
                return [false, "ui-highlight"];
              }

              if (jQuery.inArray(currDate, booked) >= 0) {
                return [true, "ui-bos"];
              } else {
                return [true];
              }

            },
            isTo1: true,
          }).on("change", function() {
            to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
          }),
          to = $("#checkout").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            minDate: new Date(firstDate),
            maxDate: new Date(lastDate),
            onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
              $("#checkin").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            },
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
              var y = date.getFullYear().toString(); // get full year
              var m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // get month.
              var d = date.getDate().toString(); // get Day
              if (m.length == 1) {
                m = '0' + m;
              } // append zero(0) if single digit
              if (d.length == 1) {
                d = '0' + d;
              } // append zero(0) if single digit
              var currDate = y + '-' + m + '-' + d;

              if (jQuery.inArray(currDate, booked) >= 0) {
                return [true, "ui-highlight-donus"];
              }


              if (jQuery.inArray(currDate, availabledays) >= 0) {
                return [true, "ui-bos"];
              }


              if (jQuery.inArray(currDate, ssdays) >= 0) {
                return [true, "ui-ss-donus"];
              } else {
                return [true];
              }
            }
          }).on("change", function() {
            from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
          });

      })
      focused = true;
          }
       });
    


    });
```

```css
.form{
  width:960px;
  margin:120px auto;
}
.form input{
  width:250px;
  padding:10px;
}
.ui-highlight .ui-state-default{background: red !important;border-color: red !important;color: white !important; cursor:no-drop;}
  .ui-bos .ui-state-default{background: green !important;border-color: green !important;color: white !important;}
  .ui-ss .ui-state-default{background: yellow !important;border-color: yellow !important;color: gray !important; cursor:help;}
  .ui-ss-donus .ui-state-default{background: yellow !important;border-color: yellow !important;color: gray !important; cursor:help;} 
  .ui-highlight-donus .ui-state-default{background: red !important;border-color: red !important;color: white !important; } 
.ui-testtarih .ui-state-default{
  background:black !important;
  color:#FFF !important;
}
```

```html
<link data-require="jqueryui" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />

   <div class="form">
    <input type="text" id="checkin" />
    <input type="text" id="checkout" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </div>
 
 <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jqueryui" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

footnote: I couldn't add my json data to stackoverflow snippet that's why I add plunker demo in plunker demo works

[Click to see plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zp2zs6m9QzOY6J6lXwqx?p=preview)

Comment: I have a feeling there might be a race condition here. You load the data on the first focus, but maybe the small delay to load the data prevents the DatePicker to be initialized correctly?

Comment: yes exactly as you said but how must be my correct code I couldn't know

Comment: You should probably load your data before the page loads in this case, or right after page load. I'll post an answer soon

Comment: my code was loaded after page load too already but I need to load after focus but problem has been fix it thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON` has a `done()` function in which you can write you logic after data is loaded. You can trigger the datepicker manually inside the done function

Here's a working [fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/kOlzcfUFPPnQplyKJG22?p=preview)

Comment: as I see nothing change on your example too ?

Comment: what do you mean, the datepicker shows up when you first click on it in my fork

Comment: data.json is being loaded when I focus but at the same time I gotta see datepicker if I focus on my input

Comment: no in your example it's not shows up datepicker for the first click :/

Comment: really I tried in a private window too but it's not working..it working like this: I see datepicker at the second click to my input

Comment: Are you sure you are opening the right link, do you see the code i added in the plunk that you open?

Comment: but as I understand your code must work logically it seems correct I understand

Comment: yes you add this: `  var elem = $(this);
      setTimeout(function(){
        elem.datepicker('show');
      },100)`

Comment: Can you increase the time for timeout function and try again(say 500, or 1000)

Comment: @ani_css This may not work for all depending upon the page load time, as the timeout is set to 100ms, maybe your page is taking more than 100ms.

Comment: @KaushalNiraula: This is NOT a proper way of coding, as on the local environment, the page may load within 100ms but the same could take more than 1000ms on the live environment

Comment: Yeah i know its a bad practice, im thinking something else that wont require a timeout

Comment: @KaushalNiraula: If you know already that it's a bad practice, then it shouldn't be suggested to people out there. In a way, you are teaching them bad code practice. Take your time to find a proper solution and then ANSWER the question, any improper solution should only be a comment.

Comment: @Sanchit found the proper solution and updated the answer

Comment: @KaushalNiraula: That's good. But remember to ONLY put a proper solution as an answer going forward. Because people don't look back at the updated answer if the bad code works for them.

Comment: @Sanchit Thanks for the tip. Will keep that in mind going forward

Answer (score 1):

It is because, on the first focus, the datepickers are applied on the elements and NOT triggered. Mind the difference between binding an event and triggering it.
On the first time focus, datepicker will be applied and NOT triggered as it is not already bound to the element. But on any subsequent focus, it would trigger the datepicker and open it since it is already bound to the element.

As a solution,you can try adding `$("#checkin").datepicker('show');` and `$("#checkout").datepicker('show');` after the end for `$("#checkin").datepicker({})` and `$("#checkout").datepicker({})`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You should load your data prior to the first focus event on your datepickers.

Here's an example :

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nhh6XrVVi5vIxenfyums?p=preview)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var data;
    $.getJSON('data.json', function (d) {
        data = d;
        console.log('data', d);
        setupDatepickers();
    });

    function setupDatepickers() {
        // use ajax data mapped to same structure as original variables
                 var firstDate = flattenFieldsArray(data.firstDate);
                 var lastDate = flattenFieldsArray(data.lastDate);
                 var availabledays = flattenFieldsArray(data.availabledays);
                 var booked = flattenFieldsArray(data.booked);;
                 var ssdays = [];

                 // nothing was changed below

                 var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
                     from       = $("#checkin")
                         .datepicker({
                             beforeShowDay : function (date) {
                                 var y = date
                                     .getFullYear()
                                     .toString(); // get full year
                                 var m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // get month.
                                 var d = date
                                     .getDate()
                                     .toString(); // get Day
                                 if (m.length == 1) {
                                     m = '0' + m;
                                 } // append zero(0) if single digit
                                 if (d.length == 1) {
                                     d = '0' + d;
                                 } // append zero(0) if single digit
                                 var currDate = y + '-' + m + '-' + d;
                                 if (jQuery.inArray(currDate, availabledays) >= 0) {
                                     return [false, "ui-highlight"];
                                 }

                                 if (jQuery.inArray(currDate, booked) >= 0) {
                                     return [true, "ui-bos"];
                                 } else {
                                     return [true];
                                 }

                             },
                             changeMonth   : true,
                             firstDay      : 1,
                             isTo1         : true,
                             maxDate       : new Date(lastDate),
                             minDate       : new Date(firstDate),
                             numberOfMonths: 2,
                             onSelect      : function (selectedDate) {
                                 var yenitarih = new Date();

                                 var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                                 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))

                                 $("#checkout").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
                             }
                         })
                         .on("change", function () {
                             to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
                         }),
                     to         = $("#checkout")
                         .datepicker({
                             beforeShowDay : function (date) {
                                 var y = date
                                     .getFullYear()
                                     .toString(); // get full year
                                 var m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // get month.
                                 var d = date
                                     .getDate()
                                     .toString(); // get Day
                                 if (m.length == 1) {
                                     m = '0' + m;
                                 } // append zero(0) if single digit
                                 if (d.length == 1) {
                                     d = '0' + d;
                                 } // append zero(0) if single digit
                                 var currDate = y + '-' + m + '-' + d;

                                 if (jQuery.inArray(currDate, booked) >= 0) {
                                     return [true, "ui-highlight-donus"];
                                 }

                                 if (jQuery.inArray(currDate, availabledays) >= 0) {
                                     return [true, "ui-bos"];
                                 }

                                 if (jQuery.inArray(currDate, ssdays) >= 0) {
                                     return [true, "ui-ss-donus"];
                                 } else {
                                     return [true];
                                 }
                             },
                             changeMonth   : true,
                             changeYear    : true,
                             firstDay      : 1,
                             maxDate       : new Date(lastDate),
                             minDate       : new Date(firstDate),
                             numberOfMonths: 2,
                             onSelect      : function (selectedDate) {
                                 $("#checkin").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                             }
                         })
                         .on("change", function () {
                             from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
                         });

    }
});
```

Comment: If you want to be extra safe, you can load your json data in your `head` tag directly by removing the `$(document).ready(function() {` line, but that would severely impact page load time

Comment: so data is being loaded after page load.but I need after focus :)